# Giving custom settings.xml to Maven Release Plugin

Tags: maven, settings, release, travis-ci

I'm trying to make releases from Travis, using the usual [Maven Release Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/). To provide a passphrase for my GPG keys (and a few other parameters) I have a `travis` branch with my settings.xml that I check out as part of my build. I then run Maven giving it a custom settings (`--settings`) and making sure this is also propagated during the release with `-Darguments`:

```
mvn release:prepare --settings ${MVN_SETTINGS} -B -V \
    -PwithMutationTests,gpg,rpm,deb \
    -Darguments="--settings ${MVN_SETTINGS}"
mvn release:perform --settings ${MVN_SETTINGS} -B -V \
    -PwithMutationTests,gpg,rpm,deb \
    -Darguments="--settings ${MVN_SETTINGS}"
```

The log indicates that my settings are passed along:

```
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/travis/build/jmxtrans/jmxtrans \
    && /usr/local/maven/bin/mvn \
        -s /tmp/release-settings1372267334822299631.xml \
        clean verify --no-plugin-updates --batch-mode \
        --settings /home/travis/build/jmxtrans/jmxtrans/target/travis/settings.xml \
        -Psonatype-oss-release -P withMutationTests,gpg,rpm,deb
```

It seems that the Maven Release Plugin also adds `-s /tmp/release-settings1372267334822299631.xml` which probably takes precedence over my settings.xml (I cannot find documentation on this).

In the end, my build fails as it cannot find my GPG key:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:1.1:sign (sign-artifacts) on project jmxtrans: Cannot obtain passphrase in batch mode -> [Help 1]
```

I am fairly certain that the settings.xml is fine and contains all necessary information: I use the same settings.xml for SNAPSHOT builds and they are GPG signed correctly.

How can I make sure that my settings are used during release?

*EDIT:*

The relevant part of my settings.xml:

```
<profile>
  <id>gpg</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
  </activation>
  <properties>
    <gpg.homedir>./target/travis/</gpg.homedir>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

The problem probably actually come from the `gpg.homedir` property being a relative path and not an absolute one. Still checking, will add an answer if that's the case.

*Additional resources:*

- [.travis.yml](https://github.com/jmxtrans/jmxtrans/blob/master/.travis.yml)
- [travis-script.sh](https://github.com/jmxtrans/jmxtrans/blob/master/travis-script.sh): used by .travis.yml to orchestrate the builds
- [settings.xml](https://github.com/jmxtrans/jmxtrans/blob/travis/settings.xml)
- [full log of failed build](https://api.travis-ci.org/jobs/56289759/log.txt?deansi=true) (sorry for the exuberant logging)

Comment: oh gosh fix your logging please (good question tough)

Comment: Yep, fixing logging is the next priority (sorry for that)

Comment: From your shell script, you could grep the tmp filename, then merge your settings.xml and run mvn release:prepare -Dresume (yep very painful)

Comment: I'd rather prefer not to do go this extreme ... and it feels like I'm just doing something wrong, there should be a way to use a custom settings.xml with the Maven Release Plugin ...

Comment: afaik as an alternative you could set a different m2_home, that's where the settings is to be copied (at least, in jenkins); you could just drop your custom settings there before running, but i wouldn't consider this less painful

Answer (score 0):

Seems that my problem was related to the GPG home directory was not an absolute path. Changing my `settings.xml` to:

```
<profile>
  <id>gpg</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
  </activation>
  <properties>
    <gpg.homedir>/home/travis/build/jmxtrans/jmxtrans/target/travis/</gpg.homedir>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

Another issue is that default preparation goal includes `clean`, which was removing the checkout of my GPG keys.